# Rshiny: DEoptim Very slow when running it in parallel mode in Rshiny

Tags: r

I have a shiny application in which i run DEOptim function. If i Run DEoptim with out parallel mode to complete 200 iterations it takes lot of time.So i tried to run it in parallel mode by specifying paralleltype=1 but even in the parallel mode it is very slow. but when i run the DEoptim in outside the Rshiny  in the parallel mode it is very fast. So is there any way to make DEoptim to execute faster when used in Rshiny?
part of the code in Rshiny with DEoptim

```
library(shiny)
library(DEoptim)
library(desirability)

prediction<-function(x,y){
    new_data<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:7,function(i){
        x[i]
    })))

    names(new_data)=c(names(y$coefficients)[2:length(names(y$coefficients))])
    pred<-predict(y,new_data)
    pred
}
optimfn<-function(x,dobj,fit,res_vec){
    model_pred<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(fit),function(i)
    {
        prediction(x,fit[[i]])
    }
  )
))
 names(model_pred)<-res_vec
 out<-predict(dobj,model_pred)
 out/-1
}
ui<-fluidPage(
     verbatimTextOutput("info1")
     )

server<-function(input, output) {
   param<-eventReactive({
   input$opt
   },{
     desire<-sapply(res_vec,function(x){
       dMin(min(prb_data[,x],na.rm=TRUE),max(prb_data[,x],na.rm=TRUE),scale = 1)
     },simplify=FALSE,USE.NAMES=TRUE)
     lower<-round(sapply(pred_vec,function(i){
           min(prb_data[,i],na.rm=TRUE)
           },simplify=TRUE,USE.NAMES = FALSE),digit=3)
    upper<-round(sapply(pred_vec,function(i){
           max(prb_data[,i],na.rm=TRUE)
           },simplify=TRUE,USE.NAMES = FALSE),digit=3)
     overallD<-do.call(dOverall,desire) 

     opt<-DEoptim(fn=optimfn,lower=lower,upper=upper,control = 
     DEoptim.control(trace = TRUE,parallelType = 1,packages=c("desirability"),parVar = c("prediction")),dobj=overallD,fit=fit,res_vec=res_vec)

     param<-round(sapply(1:length(opt$optim$bestmem),function(i){
            opt$optim$bestmem[[i]]
     },simplify=TRUE,USE.NAMES=FALSE),digit=3)
    param      
  }
 )
}
```

Comment: There is no data in your example.. So the app you posted wont do anything..